# Regex in R to match words with phonetic annotations in messy speech data

Tags: r, regex

I have rather messy speech data with phonetic annotations, such as these:

```
data <- c("hi Greg (1.57) dropped your €johnnies¿",
          "[ARF   ] what's prostitute?",
          "°wanna (get in) the €dri::ve°",
          "my €go::d I can't get out here",
          "Sco:::[       :tt↑   ]",
          "↑where have you bee:::n",
          "j's (.) lie there ((inhales sharply)) breathe",
          "well↓ i can't feel [   any?  ]")
```

I'd like to extract those word tokens that contain certain phonetic symbols, specifically "€", "°","↑", "↓", ":" and tokens with more than one upper-case letters.
The 'syntax' for the extraction would be this but the pattern is just too complex for me as the phonetic symbols can appear before the word, within the word, and after the word.

```
pattern <- ""
extract <- function(x) unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x, perl = T)))
result <- extract(data)
```

The expected result is this:

```
> result
 [1] "€johnnies¿" "ARF" "°wanna" "€dri::ve°" "€go::d" "Sco::::tt↑" "↑where"  "bee:::n" "well↓" "feel↑"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using something like for the first part your question,
although you could first do preprocessing that will remove spaces inside [ ]
like in this case `Sco:::[       :tt↑   ]`

```
[\s"]([€°↑↓:\w]*[€°↑↓:]+[€°↑↓:\w¿]*)[\s"]
```

https://regex101.com/r/nQVddI/2

Edit:

for matching more than 2 capital case letter use `([A-Z]{2,})`, i can not see examples with mixed letters like `AsDfG` should it also be matched?

Both cases: https://regex101.com/r/nQVddI/3

Comment: How is this adapted for use in R?

Comment: This works pretty nicely (except for Sco:::[      :tt↑   ]): `pattern <- "[€°↑↓:\\w]*[€°↑↓:]+[€°↑↓:\\w¿]*"`. The result is exhaustive: `> result
 [1] "€johnnies¿" "°wanna"     "€dri::ve°"  "€go::d"     "Sco:::"     ":tt↑"       "↑where"    
 [8] "bee:::n"    "well↓"      "feel↑"'

Comment: Just the words with at least two capitals are missing. How can they be integrated into the pattern?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I'll do the capital letters as well, you can regex like this one https://regex101.com/r/0vYVnk/1 to find whitespaces inside [] and replace it with nothing(then regex will work for all cases), it might be easier then making this regex more complicated

Comment: This does it quite well: `pattern <- "([€°↑↓:\\w]*[€°↑↓:]+[€°↑↓:\\w]*)|[A-Z]{2,}"`. Its output is exactly the expected result (except for "Sco:::"    ":tt↑")

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann you could try something like this: https://regex101.com/r/nQVddI/5 but you will have `Sco:::[  x*space  :tt↑` as a match instead of `Sco::::tt↑` , i don't think that joining 2 matches in one group is technically possible